# Javascript: Pass multiple arguments to EventListener and the event

Tags: javascript

i want to add an EventListener to a button via the .addEventListener Method.
Here is the code:

```
myElement[i].addEventListener('click', buttonLink);
```

This works fine and it passes the event as a value to the method. Here is the method-head:

```
function buttonLink(e) {
    //Now i can access the srcElement via:
    e.srcElement.id ...
}
```

The problem is, if i pass parameters to the method it hides the e parameter and it is completely invisible inside the method. **Is there a way to pass my own values AND(!) the event to the eventListener?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass an anonymous function to `addEventListener` and call the callback from within that:

```
myElement[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    buttonLink(e, somethingElse, anotherThing);
});
```

Comment: While this is good, this does not work with removeEventListener, as you won't be able to remove this anonymous handler.

Answer (score 3):

Below I have given 2 ways to pass the function arguments. Both works for `addEventListener` and `removeListener`:

### Method 1: Wrapper Function:

```
let myElement = document.getElementById('myId');
function wrapperFunction(e) { 
    myFunction(e, 5, 9); //define your function and pass arguments(5,9)
}

myElement.addEventListener('event', wrapperFunction);
myElement.removeEventListener('event', wrapperFunction);
```

Note: 'e' event is comes for free from the 'addEventListener' function.

### Method 2: Curring

```
var myFunction = function (arg1, arg2) {
    return function curriedFunc(e) {
      myFunction(e, arg1, arg2); // define your function and pass arguments(5,9)
    };
};

let myElement = document.getElementById('myId');
let myRef = myFunction(5,9);
myElement.addEventListener('click', myRef);
myElement.removeEventListener('click', myRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/can+I+have+multiple+arguments+in+addEventListener:

```
var someEventHander=function(event,param1,param2)
{
    console.log(event,param1,param2);
}
//add listener
document.getElementById("someid").addEventListener('click',someEventHander.bind(event,'param1','param2'), false);
```

This doesn't appear to be usable for `removeEventListener` though.