# JavaScript addEventListener problems with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the prompt: 
In the event listener DOMContentLoaded set up two `addEventListener` methods for each of the second input elements (using the array of `inputElements[]` and the corresponding index) and passing the first and the second
value (use `inputElements[].value`) and the appropriate `span` element (using `spanElements[]`). Since you need to pass arguments, use the following construct:

```
inputElements[index].addEventListener('blur',function(){ fCompareInput(arguments); })
```

This is the Function:
function fCompareinput(value1,value2,display)

This is what I have:

```
inputElements[2].addEventListener('blur', function() {
    fCompareInput(inputElements[2].value);
});
inputElements[2].addEventListener('blur', function() {
    fCompareInput(spanElements[2].value);
});

inputElements[4].addEventListener('blur', function() {
    fCompareinput(inputElements[4].value);
});
inputElements[4].addEventListener('blur', function() {
    fCompareinput(spanElements[4].value);
});
```

I don't think I'm passing the arguments correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Pass multiple arguments to EventListener and the event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053866/javascript-pass-multiple-arguments-to-eventlistener-and-the-event)

Comment: Try `this.value` instead of `inputElements[2].value`

Comment: Are you or are you not using jQuery?

Comment: This is the function:function fCompareinput(value1,value2,display)

Answer (score 0):

It's simply easier to go through your `inputElements` collection using a loop, and then bind the event listener. Also:

1. You can place multiple function calls in the `blur` callback
2. Use `this` in the callback to refer to the DOM node that has triggered the event

Let's say you only want the element with the index of `2` and `4` to have such events bound, then we can do this:

```
// Define which indexes you want to bind eventistener to
var indexes = [2,4];

// Loop through the entire collection
for (let i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
    if (indexes.indexOf(i) !== -1) {
        inputElements[i].addEventListener('blur', function() {
            fCompareinput(this.value);
            fCompareinput(spanElements[i].value);
        });
    }
}
```

Supplementary:

- If you want to retrieve all even numbered element (by index) in the collection, use:

  ```
  if (i % 2 === 0)
  ```
- If you want to retrieve all even numbered elements **and** excluding the first element, use:

  ```
  if (i % 2 === 0 && i !== 0)
  ```

For example:

```
// Loop through the entire collection
for (let i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        inputElements[i].addEventListener('blur', function() {
            fCompareinput(this.value);
            fCompareinput(spanElements[i].value);
        });
    }
}
```

---

Since you have tagged your question with **jQuery**, there is also a jQuery-based solution: much simpler, but of course incurs an overhead of having to load a library.

```
var indexes = [2,4];

$(inputElements).each(function(i) {
    if (indexes.indexOf(i) !== -1) {
        $(this).on('blur', function() {
            fCompareinput(this.value);
            fCompareinput($(spanElements).get(i).val());
        });
    }
});
```

...or, if you want to select even numbered indexes only:

```
$(inputElements).each(function(i) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        $(this).on('blur', function() {
            fCompareinput(this.value);
            fCompareinput($(spanElements).get(i).val());
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: That's an over complicated for loop if I've ever seen one.

Comment: @Baruch Over-complicated in what sense? Criticism is ok, but make sure it's constructive otherwise you're just flapping your fingers on a keyboard.

Comment: Sorry, 2, 4 and even numbers, you could just as easily had said `i % 2 === 0`. Using a `.forEach` loop will be easier than having to use the index to get the value. Since `this` a correct answer I'm not going to post mine, but here's what my example would've looked  like. https://jsfiddle.net/we5pdtau/1/

Comment: @Baruch OP simply posted two use cases: we do not know if he wants all even numbered elements (what about index 0, then? You still need to write a logic for that even with modulus), or he wants elements 2 and 4 only. `.forEach` incurs an overhead, and doesn't allow for breaking out of the loop. I don't see why the good old `for` loop is a bad thing here.

Comment: What about this `inputElements.forEach( (input, index) => (index === 2 || index === 4) ? input.addEventListener(() => fCompareInput(e.value) ) ? null);`. :P